# Some techniques and practices to gain very high levels of concentration

Tags: yoga

What are some yogic techniques other than normal meditation to develop huge amount of concentration power?

Comment: Yogic kriyas may help if you are looking something for yourself

Answer (score 0):

- Huge amount of focus and concentration can be achieved when you have suitable body and mind which can able to focus. To know more about your body and mind patterns you can start with **'Astanga Yoga'**. It has 8 limbs in which concentration is the seventh limb. before coming to that stage, you have to gain immense knowledge for prior limbs to that and practice. Then you can experience yourself the higher focus.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).